# Hitman pro deleted windows 10 dlls, and won't boot up

Tags: windows-10, crash, dll, bootrepair

I recently downloaded Hitman pro to check my computer for malware, but it flagged some windows dlls as unknown and I accidentally deleted them. As soon as that happened, the screen went gray (except for the Hitman pro application which was the only thing visible), and it prompted me to restart. I did so, and now I get to the windows loading screen with the circling dots, and the screen goes blank after that.

I have attempted to use startup repair, cmd (with bootrec /FixBoot), booting into safe mode, and even restoring a system restore point. Nothing seems to work, and it seems that the only option is to reset the computer. I don't really want to do this unless that is the only way out.

It seems that the dlls that Hitman pro deleted are essential to boot in any way, (hence safe mode not working). So, is there any way to restore those missing dlls? I have seen something called Easy Recovery Essentials, but that's $20 and I'm not sure if it will work. Is there a free program like this that will fix missing dlls and boot up problems?

Comment: Even if you were able to recover the DLLs, you would still have to make sure they were bit-for-bit correct to the original versions and you'd have to make sure they are placed back where they were before, and even then there's a good chance your computer would not work. Data recovery is OK for documents or media, where there can be minor differences in the data recovered without compromising the usability of the content. It is NOT a practical solution for missing system files.

Comment: Ok, so is there no way to fix this?

Comment: If the built-in repair options did not resolve the issue, then the only remaining way to fix it is to reset the computer.

Comment: A few things though: Windows 10 has perfectly adequate AV built-in. Why did you assume you had a virus and why did you run a third-party cleaner?

Comment: Well, yes but I was checking just to be sure. Windows defender doesn't catch everything.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just have to reset it. Thanks anyways 

Comment: For future reference, if you feel that you *need* to use a third-party tool for an extra scan above-and-beyond what Windows Defender does, utilize [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).  The on-demand scanning is absolutely free, and it will help you avoid accidents like this one.

Comment: Lol, yes I have malwarebytes premium

Comment: But Hitman pro had an option to scan for applications based on their behavior, not by their checksums.

Comment: If that's the case, scanning with three different AV/malware applications is probably just a bit of overkill. Windows Defender and Malwarebytes are both mainstream, reliable, and unlikely to cripple your operating system. And the last time that I checked, Malwarebytes premium also does heuristic analysis scans. You could have saved yourself a lot of time and effort if you had done that, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data recovery works for media and files that do not require bit-exactness to function. Documents, audio and video, images, consumer content: these all can be recovered and small imperfections in the content do not generally cause issues in their value.

HOWEVER...

DLLs and files required by programs and your operating system require much higher levels of exactness and small imperfections will result in their failure and the failure of processes that depend on them.

Because of this, while data recovery can be helpful for telling us ABOUT the system whose files it is recovering, it is generally unable to restore a system to working order when working on the file level. And the recovery tools capable of this level of recovery are the very complex and/or very expensive and exclusive tools.

In your situations, it is HIGHLY unlikely you'll be able to recover the missing files to a level sufficient to restore your system to full function.

A further point, however, is that Hitman may have been correct in identifying the files as being malicious, in which case you don't actually want them recovered, and a reinstall is the correct course of action.